# Need some explanation about interface in LibreOffice basic

Tags: libreoffice-basic

I need to program something in LibreOffice Basic, but I've never done that before. I just have the basis in python, so it's really new for me.
I didn't find any recent documentation, so I'm reading the basic guide from 2010.

But there is a point I really don't understand, They speak about various interface but I don't succeed to understand their interest and when I should call it.

If you can explain it I would love it.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't go deeper, no need. To write working code in Basic, you do not need additional information - you just need to know the list of methods of each object, no more. Which interface provided this method to the object shouldn't bother you.

See chapter *3.6.4. Interfaces* in [**Pitonyak's book**](http://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt). The list of available methods is easy to obtain using the [**MRI**](https://github.com/hanya/MRI) or [Xray tool](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_development_basic#Xray_tool) extension. MRI is convenient in that after an in-depth study of the object, you immediately get a piece of code ready for use.

[image: MRI Code Snippet]

(Unfortunately, this extension works extremely [**unstable with the latest versions of LibreOffice**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/303739/need-help-to-get-mri-to-work-on-lo-7x/))

**Update** [Video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/DHgblImh4lQ)

Comment: Thank you for that answer ! I'm working on libreoffice 6.2.8 so I guess MRI is fine for me. You say that MRI is better for a beginner like me than xray ? I just installed xray and I'm reading the book to understand how it function, but if MRI is better for my use, I'll just dl it.

Comment: I was hoping to quickly find some video on YouTube that would demonstrate the techniques of working with MRI and was upset! Either I looked badly, or really no one made such a video. I'm ready to quickly record a video now, but I don't want to invent an example of a problem. Please, describe the task that you are going to program, I will take this as an example.

Comment: the task I'm going to program is really complex. I'll just take a part of it. I'll send you a file, with in the first sheet the raw data and in the second a part of what I'm wanting to do. I guess it'll do for the beginning, I don't want you to do everything ! https://www.mediafire.com/file/rkjaf2q9wlaz7xn/example_file.ods/file

Comment: BTW : pick what do you want as example in the file I sent you

Comment: So, just reformat raw data and add 6 formulas? Well, please wait - when it will done I'll add link to my answer

Comment: No that's not just it. I need to add a different formula in each columns, the number of columns can change. In a sheet I need to add a dropdown list add a chart etc .. I have a lot to do and my chief just wants to click on one button to have the result. but it's to much for an exemple and I thought this could fit for just an example

Comment: If the problem looks exactly as you just described, then perhaps [**this comment**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=105064#p509881) by @Villeroy (and several next) will help you solve the problem without a macro at all? (Trust me, this guy knows what he's talking about)

Answer (score 1):

Python is very good when working with LibreOffice. See http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html.

You'll still need MRI or XrayTool and Pitonyak's book as explained by @JohnSUN. Also you'll want [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python) and a reference such as https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python.

For a single small project though, Basic may be better as there are more examples available.